# Why is an incoming server request with query string containing "gclid" malformed?

Tags: google-analytics

Our web server is throwing errors into the log for requests that are formatted as follows:

`/?&gclid=EAIaIxobChMI5ufgqs6b7xIVkcDACh0hkgqEExAYASAAxgJd1Px_BxE`

In plain English, this is a request to our home page with a GA query string appended in the query string. Notice how the third character is `&`. This is suspect to me because the `&` is not preceded by a `key=value` pair.

When I send a request manually via `https://www.example.com/?&gclid=EAIaIxobChMI5ufgqs6b7xIVkcDACh0hkgqEExAYASAAxgJd1Px_BxE` I notice that it also triggers a 307 redirect, ostensibly because of our server's security configurations.

My understanding is that requests containing the `gclid` query string parameter are automatically generated when users click on Google ads, so it’s a bit odd that Google would be appending a “malformed” query string.

My logs also show requests in this format:

`/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=xx&utm_term=some%20search%20term&&gclid=ExIaxQobChMIusDx4tSa7gIVxD2tBx1BQwx6EAAxASAxEgIp9fD_BxE`

Notice the two `&&` characters that precede `gclid`.

It should be noted that we're running ads on two different sites on this same server, and this issue only affects one of the sites. This indicates that it could be an issue with the specific ad on this site. Something to do with Tracking Templates or Custom Parameters in the ad setup.

Why might this be happening?

Comment: "When I send a request manually..." What happens when you remove the spurious `&`? And how are the requests normally made? Is it from your own code? If so, show an example.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice when I remove the `&` there is no 307 redirect. The request is not being made from our own code. It's possible that the request URL is being generated on some other website, but I can't currently think of a way to figure out what the true referrer is, as our logger is either showing a blank referrer or the URL in question being the referrer.

Comment: Surely it is not the automatic tagging of Google Ads that generates that code, it is something that happens on the site or due to a poorly managed redirect.

Comment: @MichelePisani I added another example. `/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=xx&utm_term=some%20search%20term&&gclid=ExIaxQobChMIusDx4tSa7gIVxD2tBx1BQwx6EAAxASAxEgIp9fD_BxE` -- Notice the two `&&` chars. Any ideas?

Comment: Considering that you put the utm by hand and the glic hangs it by itself, it seems that all the urls you have contain the & at the end. How is the link of a clicked URL that is not campaign?